# Вставка элемента в фигурные скобки в html

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте! Есть такой html код:

```
<title>{title}</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="{keywords}">
```

Вместо `{title}` и `{keywords}` вставляется информация из базы данных. Не могу понять как это происходит. Впервые встречаюсь с такой конструкцией. Может кто-то сможет привести пример или просто описать как это работает

Comment: Видимо у вас какой-то шаблонизатор используется, он и делает подстановку данных.

Comment: @Visman, я тоже так подумал, но в коде вроде ничего такого нет. А можно это как-то проверить?

Comment: @Visman, А можно как-то самому написать мини шаблонизатор и потом его заюзать?

Comment: Можно https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: В первую очередь нужно определить на каком этапе происходит подстановка значений: на стороне веб-сервера, когда в браузер отправляется страничка с уже подставленными значениями, или на стороне браузера. когда сервер отдаёт страничку-шаблон, а подстановка происходит на стороне клиента. Судя из того что подстановка в мета-тегах смею предположить что подстановка происходит таки на стороне сервера. Шаблонизаторов которые могут так делать великое множество. необходим код приложения.

Comment: еще трешевый вариант - сгенерить страницу в буфер, а потом обычной заменой пройтись :D

Comment: @r.mcreal [Уже всё написали](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), такие велосипеды больше не нужны

Comment: В итог сделал так: `$arr = showTags($temp['page']); ?>
    <title><?=$arr['title']?></title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?=$arr['keywords']?>">
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?=$arr['description']?>">`. Наверно это ужасно, но все вроде работает. Что думаете?

Answer (score 1):

Это простой шаблонизатор. Принцип работы

```
str_replace("{title}", $title, "<title>{title}</title>");
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Comment: а разве `str_replace` может делать замену к коде? Тем более в html. P.S. пример который я привел это часть страницы, а не строка

Comment: Так ты не забывай про контектст. Этот файл инклюдится в PHP скрипт, тот его обработал и вывел в контексте работы скрипта.